# Motion recognition basics?

Tags: image, image-processing, image-recognition, motion-detection

Scenario: I want to take input from the laptop camera and detect the user moving his finger at a virtual point in the air.

I have not idea where to start :) What library to do the heavy lifting would you suggest? What topics should I read?

My optimal case would be something cross platform.

Comment: Consider buying a sensor that will do the work for you. https://leapmotion.com/
Aside from that, look into "optical flow" algorithms. Even if you use OpenCV as vsz suggested, find a good book on image processing to learn the fundamentals. A popular introductory textbook is Digital Image Processing by Gonzalez and Woods.

Answer (score 1):

With absolutely no prior knowledge in pattern recognition I would advise something very basic and simple. Try to create, open, display, draw on images in **opencv**, and when you feel comfortable with it, try subtracting two consecutive images from the video. When you have that image containing the difference between two frames, you can start with the more advanced algorithms (segmentation, etc.). You can start with a simple thresholding, and refine your results with simple morphological operations, and if the results are still not good enough, you can search for more advanced segmentation algorithms.

Comment: Sounds like reasonable start. Thank you very much for your response!